# Image is not defined (Firebase storage - React Native)

Tags: image, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

The problem: 
I am able to successfully upload an image to firebase storage, but when I try to sign-out, then sign-in again, I am stucked on the log-in page. and after few minutes this error appears

[image]

This is my code on fetching the image and log-in

```
 if (currentUser != null) {
          uid = currentUser.uid;
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
          console.log("uid")
          console.log(uid)
          console.log("currentUser")
          console.log(currentUser)
          console.log("docRef")
          console.log(docRef)
          docRef.get().then((doc) => {
            console.log("doc");
            console.log(doc);
            if (doc.exists) {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
               const userData = doc.data();

              const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/userProfilePictures/${uid}`).child('profile.jpg');
              imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
              dispatch({ type: GET_PROFILE_PICTURE, payload: url })
              dispatch({ type: GET_USER_DATA, payload: userData});
              Actions.home();

            }).catch((error) => {
              dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_PICTURE, payload: ''})
              console.log(error);
            })
            } else {
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          });

        }else {
          console.log('something went wrong');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        loginUserFail(dispatch)
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
```

After loggin in again, it seems that the user is authenticated, but It can't execute this line   docRef.get().then((doc) => { there is no error on the console.log.

And then if you try to reload again, then sign-in again you can see the newly uploaded image.

Comment: Looks like `import {Image} from 'react-native'` is needed

Comment: @Cherniv hmm, after I have reloaded my simulator I can see the newly updated image. so the Image component is actually working